# Django: view for handling ModelChoiceField

Tags: django, forms, view

I have a GET form with checkboxes. When i select several boxes and submit the form  it produces a link with several variables with the same name. How do i get each value of those variables in the view?

```
class SearchJobForm(ModelForm):
    query = forms.CharField()
    types = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=JobType.objects.all(), widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple())
    class Meta:
        model = Job
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`request.GET` is a `QueryDict` instance that has a [`getlist`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.QueryDict.getlist) method. If you call

```
request.GET.getlist('mykey')
```

you'll get back a list with all the values, e.g. if the querystring is `mykey=1&mykey=2`, you'll get `['1', '2']` from `getlist`.

If you use the [`MultipleChoiceField`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/fields/#multiplechoicefield), Django handles this automatically for you.

Answer (score 0):

Give every checkbox a different name attribute. How do you generate your checkboxes?